# Display text from list of variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

I have a series of pages on my site that utilize JavaScript to show a title based on the variable defined in the page.

Basic HTML

```
<h1 id="pageTitle"></h1>
<script> var page = "start";</script>
<!-- Rest of the page... -->
```

Separate JavaScript File

```
var startText = "Hello!";
var middleText = "This is a page";
var endText = "Example";

if(page == 'start'){
  $('#pageTitle').html(startText);
}
if(page == 'middle'){
  $('#pageTitle').html(middleText);
}
if(page == 'end'){
  $('#pageTitle').html(endText);
}
```

This follows a simple pattern that does the job fine, but can get tedious as the website grows. Is there a cleaner way to get the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining a JS variable in every page I suggest to attach a `data-*` attribute to the title tag like :

```
<h1 id="pageTitle" data-page="start"></h1>
```

Then in your separate JS file, you could create an object contains the list of `title` and use the `data-page` attributes as a key like :

```js
var titles = {
  "start": "Hello!",
  "middle": "This is a page",
  "end": "Example"
}

var title_element = $("#pageTitle");
var key = title_element.data('page');

title_element.text(titles[key]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="pageTitle" data-page="middle"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an object reference the key...

```js
var messages = {
  "foo" : "bar",
  "hello" : "world"
}

function setMessage(key) {
   document.querySelector("#out").innerHTML = messages[key];
}

setMessage("hello");
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way could be to organize the titles in a dictionary.

```
var titles = {
  "start": "Hello!",
  "middle": "This is a page",
  "end": "Example"
}

$('#pageTitle').html(titles[page]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to organize your code into modular functions. This will help keep your code maintainable.

```js
function init(title) {
  document.querySelector("#pageTitle").innerHTML = getTitleHtml(title);
}

function getTitleHtml(title) {
  const titleMap = {
    start: "Hello",
    middle: "This is a page",
    end: "Example"
  };
  return titleMap[title];
}

var title = "end";
init(title);
```

```html
<h1 id="pageTitle"></h1>
```