# Display multiple instances of text from a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

This is a follow-up to my previous question: [Display text from list of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318476/display-text-from-list-of-variables)

Using the previous solution, how do I execute it multiple times on a single page?

Here's what I have:

HTML & JQuery

```
<p>This is a price: <span class="price" data-cost="abc"></span>.</p>
<p>This is another price: <span class="price" data-cost="def"></span>.</p>

<script>
  var prices={
    "abc" : "$10",
    "def" : "$250"
  }
  var price_element=$(".price");
  var price_key = price_element.data('cost');
  price_element.text(prices[price_key]);
</script>
```

Currently, this displays all prices as "$10", instead of reacting to the data-cost. Would I use some sort of For loop or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `.each` loop and then an instance of `this`

```
$(".price").each(function() {
    let cost = prices[$(this).data("cost")];
    $(this).text(cost);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should iterate through elements, because `$(".price")` returns an iterable entity of elements (not a single element), so you can iterate through them via `.each()` jQuery method, like this:

```js
var prices = {
  "abc" : "$10",
  "def" : "$250"
}

$(".price").each(function() {
  var cost = $(this).data('cost');
  $(this).text(prices[cost]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a price: <span class="price" data-cost="abc"></span>.</p>
<p>This is another price: <span class="price" data-cost="def"></span>.</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check the below snippet. Hope you are looking for it.

```js
var prices = {
    "abc" : "$10",
    "def" : "$250"
},
priceElement,
i;

priceElement= $(".price");

for (i = 0; i < priceElement.length; i++) {
    var elem = $(priceElement[i]),
        priceKey = elem.data("cost");
        
    $(elem).text(prices[priceKey]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a price: <span class="price" data-cost="abc"></span>.</p>
<p>This is another price: <span class="price" data-cost="def"></span>.</p>
```